# Boy moves to a town with sinkholes and a tunnel society

Tags: story-identification, books

I don’t know when I read this book, but it was a book about a boy who moved to a town with a sinkhole problem.

He ends up meeting a girl who introduces him to a tunnel society where they use items to hold up the tunnel walls and ceilings. When one of these items falls it causes sinkholes. She takes him to a meeting with a bunch of people, but I don't know what happened next. I'm not even sure if I finished the book.

I remember the boy had no friends and he hated moving there.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you give us a _range of years_ in which you were likely to have read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: In the last 7-4 years. The cover might’ve had a boy and a girl, with the girl ahead, running through a tunnel full of miscellaneous items.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be [*The Lifters*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2333204) (2018) by Dave Eggers.

[image: Cover of "The Lifters" showing a house on a hillside beneath a full moon. In the foreground the hill is cut away to show branching tunnels, braced with random items including a grandfather clock, a sofa, and a bicycle. Gran and Catalina are running through a tunnel with a hand torch.]

The blurb [on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/35734857-the-lifters) notes that a boy moves to a new town that has a problem with sinking:

> When Gran and his family move to Carousel, he has no idea that the town is built atop a secret. Little does he suspect, as he walks his sister to school or casually eats a banana, that mysterious forces lurk mere inches beneath his feet, tearing up the earth like mini-hurricanes and causing the town to slowly but surely sink.
>
> When Gran's friend, the difficult-to-impress Catalina Catalan, presses a silver handle into a hillside and opens a doorway to underground, he knows that she is extraordinary and brave, and that he will have no choice but to follow wherever she leads. With luck on their side, and some discarded hockey sticks for good measure, Gran and Catalina might just find a way to lift their town--and the known world--out of danger.

And a review notes a girl propping up the town with random items from underneath:

> a town falling into sink holes that are supported by various items like hockey sticks in tunnels placed there by a young girl